# how to use doctrine getArrayResult to return just row id and name?

Tags: arrays, doctrine-orm, dql

hi i have this dql query

```
createQuery("SELECT b.name FROM Album\Entity\Brand b")->getArrayResult();
```

it returns this

```
array
 0 => 
  array
   'id' => int 11
   'name' => string 'aaas' (length=4)
```

what can i do to turn result to something like this

```
array(11=>'asss')
```

i mean array like

```
array(id=>name,id=>name,...)
```

is there any specific option in dql or getArrayResult method for this problem?

Comment: This is not a _problem_. I returns the data as it is in the db. You should retrieve this array and built your own based on this array.

Comment: yes i know , but i believe doctrine must have simpler way for generating simple array results

Answer (score 4):

I just came across this problem last night. The thing you want to do is not possible, not entirely anyway.

If you decide to retrieve the whole entity object rather than name only you could use something like this:

```
createQuery("SELECT b FROM Album\Entity\Brand b INDEX BY b.id")->getArrayResult();
```

... and as a result you will get:

```
Array(
    [id] => object,
    ....
);
```

However, if you do:

```
createQuery("SELECT b.name FROM Album\Entity\Brand b INDEX BY b.id")->getArrayResult();
```

... well, INDEX BY gets ignored. Not really sure why.

This guy [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12096792/using-column-value-as-array-index-in-doctrine) seems to have **solved** the problem but he uses Doctrine 2.1 whereas I have 2.0. Which version have you used?

Answer (score 0):

Because you have to write :

```
createQuery("SELECT b.id, b.name FROM Album\Entity\Brand b INDEX BY b.id")->getArrayResult();
```

More complex example:

```
$u = $em-> createQuery('SELECT u.id, u.name FROM MainBundle:User u INDEX BY u.id')->getArrayResult();
```