# Using column value as array index in doctrine

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I am using doctrine 2.1 in order to create a model for `settings` table:

```
id |  arg  |  value  |  category
1  |  name |  foo    |  general_settings 
2  |  desc |  bar    |  general_settings
```

Suppose that I have a lot of setting for different categories. In order to get all the setting  for a specific category I do something like this:

```
$q = Doctrine_Query::create()
    ->from('Setting p')
    ->where('p.category = ?', $category_name);
```

Everything works fine at this point. Well.. the question of $64,000 is: 
Do exist a data access alternative that allow me to read the result as below?

```
$resultSet = $q->execute(); 

//the magic here could be use the -arg- column as index
$requested_setting = $resulSet['name']  

//print the setting value
echo $requested_setting['value'];  //should prints "foo"

//another way
echo $resulSet['desc']['value']; //should prints "bar"
```

Answer (score 68, accepted):

I got it: the trick here is use the `INDEX BY` word.

#### Query class

import the Query class (no always optional):

```
use \Doctrine\ORM\Query;
```

create the query:

```
$query = $this->data->em->createQuery('
    SELECT s 
    FROM models\Setting s 
    INDEX BY s.arg //to set array custom key
    WHERE s.category = :category');
$query->setParameter('category', 'general');
```

set the hidration mode in order to work with read-only arrays

```
$settings = $query->getResult(Query::HYDRATE_ARRAY);
```

Display the value:

```
echo $settings['desc']['value'];  // prints "bar"
```

#### QueryBuilder

With the `QueryBuilder` object you can set the index at the `from` statement:

```
$qb = $em->createQueryBuilder();
$qb->select('s');
$qb->from('models\Settings', 's', 's.arg');  // here the magic
$result = $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
```

Then, you can access the object as:

```
$description = $result['desc'];
$value = $description->getValue();
```

Comment: you are getting way to little love for the QueryBuilder solution. Couldn't find it in the Doctrine documention... Thanks allot :)

Comment: If you're querying only specific fields like `SELECT s.arg FROM [...] INDEX BY s.id` *don't forget to add the field you want to index by* too. E.g., if you want to index by `s.id` use `SELECT s.id, s.arg FROM [...] INDEX BY s.id`. Otherwise Doctrine won't have your index value in its result rows and so the query's result will be a regular indexed array instead of an associative one.

Comment: Thank you flu!, I couldn't find why it wasn't using the index by

Comment: For reference, you can find the `indexBy` option in the QueryBuilder methods listing for `from` and `join`. http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/query-builder.html#high-level-api-methods

Comment: that was amazing!

Comment: This answer is quite old. Now you can use ->indexBy() method in a query builder.

Comment: Thumbs up for _don't forget to add the field you want to index by_!

Answer (score 21):

FYI when using createQueryBuilder in your EntityRepository, you can directly specify the INDEX BY along with the alias:

```
$this->createQueryBuilder('p', 'p.id')
```

This avoids handling manually the from which is automatically handled in EntityRepositories.

Answer (score 1):

Doctrine IndexBy function is used, to display column value as array index

```
$this
// database table alias
->createQueryBuilder( 'app_settings' )
// first parameter should be alias and second parameter will be column name, which you want to show as array index
->indexBy('app_settings','app_settings.name')
// get query
->getQuery()
// get doctrine result in array format
->getArrayResult();
```

The result of mentioned query will be in this format:
[Result of mentioned query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QT5sM.png)

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of completeness, when using `NativeQuery`, the index of the result array can be defined in the `ResultSetMapping` object. For example, by using the `addIndexByScalar` method.

```php
$rsm = new ResultSetMapping();

$rsm->addScalarResult('ctime', 'ctime', 'datetime');
$rsm->addScalarResult('id', 'id', 'integer');
$rsm->addIndexByScalar('id'); // ← 

$stm = $this->getEntityManager()->createNativeQuery("SELECT ctime, id FROM table", $rsm);
$stm->getArrayResult();
```