# Symfony doctrine using column value as array key when using joins

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, query-builder

I've tried to find how to use column value as array key when getting results using queryBuilder. I found this question [Using column value as array index in doctrine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12096792/using-column-value-as-array-index-in-doctrine) but unfortunately it doesn't work in my case as I'm using left join.

Currently I have this query:

```
        $qb = $entityManager->createQueryBuilder('translation');
    $qb->select('translation')
        ->from('MainBundle:PageTranslation', 'translation', 'translation.id')
        ->leftJoin('MainBundle:Page', 'page', 'WITH', 'IDENTITY(translation.page) = page.id')
        ->where('translation.locale = :locale')
        ->andWhere('translation.enabled = :enabled')
        ->andWhere('page.category = :category')
        ->setParameter('category', $category)
        ->setParameter('locale', $locale)
        ->setParameter('enabled', true);
    $result = $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
```

Results I get has array keys starting with 0 and incrementing by one. I need array keys to be Page IDs (page.id) or IDENTITY of translation.page

Comment: Does each page have only one translation? I remember trying something like this with 'INDEX BY' with a oneToMany association and it didn't work out well, i.e: you won't get a nested array as a mapping from page to translations, but each page id will only have **one** translation assigned to it.

Comment: No each page may have multiple translations

Comment: Then I suggest you do it manually.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the [QueryBuilder API](http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/orm/2.2/class-Doctrine.ORM.QueryBuilder.html) you'll see that the `innerJoin()` method has `$indexBy` as it's last argument. Pass `'translation.id'` or ( the pk of translation instead of 'id') as the last argument, to get the desired result.

Comment: If I add `indexBy` argument I get error `[Syntax Error] line 0, col 100: Error: Expected Literal, got 'BY'`