# Doctrine - use column value as array index

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

I have this query:

```
$qb = $this
        ->_em
        ->createQueryBuilder();

    $qb
        ->select('f.name', 'f.id')
        ->from('Bundle:F', 'f', 'f.id');
    return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
```

which returns the result like this:

```
array:438[▼
    214 => array:2[▼
       "name" => "xxx"
       "id" => 214
    ]
    215 => array:2[▼
       "name" => "yyy"
       "id" => 215
    ]
    ...
```

But I don't want sub-arrays and want the result to be returned like this:

```
array:438[▼
    214 => "xxx"
    215 => "yyy"
    ...
```

i.e. `id` as the key and `name` as the value. Is that possible?

Comment: I think this may help you : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12096792/using-column-value-as-array-index-in-doctrine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use and array_column to fix it in the array.

```
$arr = array_column($qb, "name", "id");
```

This will isolate the id column and use that as key, and isolate name column and use that as values.

Answer (score 2):

```
$result =  $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
return array_column($result, "name", "id");
```