# Symfony - Index by for getting count of child nodes based on parent node

Tags: php, symfony, query-builder

I have a query that gives me a set of 'Companies' (in variable $companies) and i have another query that return the count of child companies that exist for the companies fetched earlier (in $companies). The query result is accurate, but I am having trouble knowing which 'childCount' belongs to which company.

Given below is the list of companies

```
array:3 [▼
  0 => Company {#707 ▶}
  1 => Company {#720 ▶}
  2 => Company {#723 ▶}
]
```

Given below is the query result returning the count

```
array:2 [▼
  0 => array:1 [▼
    "childCount" => "3"
  ]
  1 => array:1 [▼
    "childCount" => "1"
  ]
]
```

Note: 1 out of 3 companies have no child companies.

```
//$companies variable has list of companies for which we have to find child companies

 public function getSubCompanies($companies)
    {
        $queryBuilder = $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder();
        $queryBuilder
                    ->select('count(c) as childCount')
                    ->from('AppBundle:Company','c','c.id')
                    ->where('c.parentId IN (:parentId)')
                    ->setParameter('parentId',$companies)
                    ->addGroupBy('c.parentId')

        ;

        return $queryBuilder->getQuery()->getResult();
    }
```

I want the default indexes (0 and 1) to be replaced with the parent company id's, like shown below

```
array:2 [▼
  parentCompanyId1 => array:1 [▼
    "childCount" => "3"
  ]
  parentCompanyId2 => array:1 [▼
    "childCount" => "1"
  ]
]
```

Comment: Getting exactly what you want from a query will be a bit challenging but simply adding parentId to the select statement will get the information you need.  After that, if you really need it in your desired format then use a bit of php to transform the results.

Answer (score 0):

after the `->select` just add some more info like

```
->addSelect('c.parentId')
```

the resulting array should then be like (I obviously don't know your parentIds):

```
array:2 [▼
  0 => array:1 [▼
    "childCount" => "3",
    "parentId" => "13"
  ]
  1 => array:1 [▼
    "childCount" => "1"
    "parentId" => "16"
  ]
]
```

to transform that into the appropriate format:

```
$result = [];
foreach($queryResult as $row) {
    $result[$row['parentId']] = $row; 
    // maybe even unset the parentId afterwards ...
}
```

Comment: Yes, i agree with this solution, but it involves looping through the queryResult. I was checking for a way to get the desired result right after the query runs. Thanks for this idea.

Comment: @ARIFAK slightly less interesting ... but you could try to make something like this work: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12096792/using-column-value-as-array-index-in-doctrine

Answer (score 0):

to solve the issue, i have defined an entity 'children' which has a OneToMany relationship with the same table 'Company' and is mapped by 'parentId'

oneToMany:
        children:
            targetEntity: AppBundle\Entity\Company
            mappedBy: parentId
            cascade: ["persist"]

the count of children gives me the count of the child companies within a table, will post additional code if anyone needs more clarity on solution. Thanks for helping @Jakumi and @Cerad